# How to keep running the same GraphQL query until x is null?

Tags: python, tableau-api

I have a Tableau GraphQL query that requires pagination:

```
test_1 = """
{
  fieldsConnection (
    first: 10,
    orderBy: {field: NAME, direction: ASC}) {

nodes {
  name
  }
}
pageInfo {
  hasNextPage
  endCursor
    }
  }
}
"""
```

2nd query:

```
test_2 = """
{
  fieldsConnection (
    first: 10,
    next: SOME_STRING
    orderBy: {field: NAME, direction: ASC}) {

nodes {
  name
  }
}
pageInfo {
  hasNextPage
  endCursor
    }
  }
}
"""
```

This first query will have `hasNextPage = true` and `endCursor = "huge-ass-string"`. What I saw in my server is that to extract all fields of interest I need to run the query 13 times!

What I want to do is in Python, using `from tableau_api_lib import TableauServerConnection as tsc`, write a function that runs the first query (test_1). If `hasNextPage` is true, than run the second query (test_2) updating the `next` value to be the value we got from `endCursor`.

This is how I get the JSON response from my query:

```
response = conn.metadata_graphql_query(query = test_1)
```

Is this possible in Python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just implemented pagination in the query and kept looping and storing the extracted data in a DataFrame